# How does the katakana lengthening mark (長音符) sort?

Tags: kana, sorting-order

Usually, lists are collated using the gozyuuon order. But how does the katakana lengthening mark `ー` fit in?

Given the following sequence of words, what order should they be in? What are the sorting rules regarding katakana?

```
合格{ごうかく}
航空{こうくう}
項目{こうもく}
効力{こうりょく}
呼応{こおう}
氷{こおり}
コーナー
コーヒー
コーラー
```

Comment: +1 - Great question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the wiki articles [五十音順](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ja/wiki/%E4%BA%94%E5%8D%81%E9%9F%B3%E9%A0%86) and [日本語文字列照合順番](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ja/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E7%85%A7%E5%90%88%E9%A0%86%E7%95%AA), there is an Industrial Standard (JIS X 4061) specifying the ordering of kana, though sometimes not strictly followed.

The lengthening mark will be changed to あいうえお according to the previous kana, and ん if the previous kana is ん, and the changed word would be used in sorting. If two changed word forms are the same but the original one is different, then the one changed from the lengthening mark would come after: ああ→あー

The words you listed should be ordered as:

```
合格{ごうかく}
航空{こうくう}
項目{こうもく}
効力{こうりょく}
呼応{こおう}
コーナー
コーヒー
コーラー
氷{こおり}
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing. The page for the original industrial standard can be reached by typing "X4061" in the first text space and doing the search in this page: http://www.jisc.go.jp/app/JPS/JPSO0020.html.

Comment: @sawa I found the page, I cannot read the file due to adobe reader problems.

Comment: It says you need the latest version of adobe reader to open it. It may be troublesome. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That is the most common way, but there are some others. The Japanese library cataloguing standard 日本目録規則, most of encyclopaedias and some dictionaries just ignore the lengthening marks.

http://sist-jst.jp/handbook/sist13/sist13_k.htm
７．２　五十音順配列
五十音順配列は，和文索引において最も広く行われている配列方式である。五十音順配列と称されるものには，大きく分けて，「国語辞典配列」と「百科事典配列」の２種類がある。どちらも見出しの「読み」に基づいた字順配列であるが，大きな違いは，長音の扱いである。長音のある場合に，直前の文字の母音を長音において繰り返すのが「国語辞典配列」，長音を無視するのが「百科事典配列」と呼んで大過ないと思われる。本基準では，後者の「百科事典配列」により，五十音順配列を記述した。これは，一般的な用語辞典，百科事典，索引類のほとんどが「百科事典配列」を採用しているからである。